# How to get the ouput of 'Git Clone' command while using in ProcessStartInfo in C#?

Tags: c#, git

```
static void Main(string[] args){
            ProcessStartInfo gitInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            gitInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            gitInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            gitInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            gitInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe";

            Process gitProcess = new Process();
            gitInfo.Arguments = "clone https://github.com/barunhalderkolkata/TestGitHub.git"; 
            gitInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\barunh\Desktop\filters";

            gitInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            gitProcess.StartInfo = gitInfo;
            gitProcess.Start();

            string stderr_str = gitProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();  
            string stdout_str = gitProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 

            gitProcess.WaitForExit();
            gitProcess.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(stdout_str);
            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I am getting null in *stdout_str*. But I'd like to have the output as same as it used to show  in Git terminal such as-

Cloning into 'TestGitHub'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.(delta 0)

Checking connectivity... done.

Comment: If git.exe isn't writing to the stdout stream (e.g. uses some lower-level I/O mechanism to write directly to the console window), you won't get any output. What happens when you redirect from the command line? In any case, note that your basic approach is flawed: synchronously attempting to read from both stderr and stdout in the same thread is prone to deadlock. See docs for the `Process` class for more details on that issue.

Comment: got it, by giving '--progress' filter in clone command we can have the out put of the command in StandardError, although forcefully.